# Which is best for learning how to do a certain thing: writing your own or looking at someone else's?

Tags: learning, coding

Often when I'm writing code to do a certain thing, I'm faced with either writing my own or using someone else's code. Assume here that this "thing" is something that I've never done before and am interested in learning how it's done.

**Which would you say is better from a learning perspective: try writing your own solution; or looking at code by someone else?** I've always written my own code if I have an idea on how to do it, but resorted to looking at someone else's when I don't have a clue. I believe that the best is probably a combination of both: make your own attempt and then look at how someone else did.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First try to write your own.  Then look at someone else's solution.

Comment: +1: Every developer should know that it's a lot harder if the answers aren't 'at the back of the book'.

Comment: Also, ask for suggestions as soon as you have some starting idea, as well as after finished writing your first version.

Comment: First doing it yourself makes it clear in your mind 1) what you need and 2) what you should look for.  We are very careful about letting foreign code in as it usually do something else than you need, but I just _love_ the Google Guava library.

Answer (score 8):

If I really want to learn how to do X and someone's got a sample online, going through the sample really speeds up how quickly I can write it myself.  Stepping through their code gives you one possible starting place on where the code can end up.  I may end up with my own code that is no where near the example, but the example got me to that decision.

If the sample is gold code, then I may incorporate it into what I'm doing, but 9 times out of 10 the sample is not quite what I was looking for.  In those cases I'll use what I learned with the sample and build my own.

Comment: +1 for hack a sample first... having a working sample of something I have no point of reference is vastly better than trying to get the IDEA while simultaneously figuring out all the little gotchas

Comment: @Bill - exactly my point!

Comment: I always try to start this way even though I always end up trashing the example before I am done.  I almost never find examples with the right amount of flexibility, but seeing it work hardcoded, or stripping down a over-engineered version still helps me get the idea faster than trying to get there from the manuals most times.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the size of the required solution and the community feedback to any existing solution.

Useing web dev as an example, I can write a forum but wouldn't bother, just use a respected well known solution, almost anything smaller write myself.

Answer (score 0):

Something closely related that I just realised today....

Things that I learn by writing my own program for a *real life* solution to something stick with me a lot more than doing samples/tutorial/exercises just for the sake of learning.

Walking through a tutorial or sample of something new is good as a basic learning exercise, but if I then walk away from it and have to apply it three weeks later (without looking at that technology at all since), I'll tend to have to Google things, revisit, look up, etc, a lot more than if I did a real program in it. It's only when I actually create something from scratch for myself in a given programming language or technology that it really sticks, and that I *internalize* the knowledge.